# check if collectionView scroll top

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to know, when my collectionView hit top of the screen. There is a lot of similar topics suggest following:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
        NSLog(@"At the top");
}
```

However, its not work for me. I have `collectionView` declared as following:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (self.myCollectionView.contentOffset.y == 0)
        NSLog(@"At the top");
}
```

Not work either. Delegate is set through storyboard.

How to detect when my collection view scroll to top?? Why that method isn't calling?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn"t work" ? Is `scrollViewDidScroll:` at least called?

Comment: @Larme yes its called, but it doesn't react on behaviour of self.myCollectionView.

Answer (score 6):

It should work there must be something wrong with your `collectionViewDelegate`. Because `UICollectionViewDelegate` Confirms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. So all of `scrollViewDelegates` should work with `collectionViewDelegate`.

[image: Apple Docs Screenshot]

Try changing your code

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0)
    NSLog(@"At the top");
}
```

Comment: i know, thats weird, in fact, method called many times but look like it have no connection with self.myCollectionView. My solution is: - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
,     float edge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
 if (edge <= scrollView.contentSize.height) NSLog (@"At the top).

Comment: Just make sure that you explicitly adopt UIScrollViewDelegate in your class.